# custom shaped body in HTML using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to code the following layout using HTML,CSS,and javascript.

http://tinypic.com/r/zvzd6g/5

I cant figure out how can i make the slideshow in the layout with the same shape.Taking the images and make it to same shape in photoshop is the better way. i tried taking the background image for section with a shape on top but can tile the bottom of the image. here is my html and css code .please note the code which i give is a sample code with dummy text

here is my code

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* new clearfix */
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

body {
    background: #CCC;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1 { font-size: 360%; }

h2 { font-size: 240%; }

h3 { font-size: 210%; }

h4 { font-size: 180%; }

h5 { 
    font-size: 160%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h6 { font-size: 140%; }

#wrapper {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
    background: url(../img/bg.png) bottom repeat;
}

footer {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #815b36, #3d2304);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #815b36, #3d2304);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #815b36, #3d2304);
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}

.links {
    width:100%;
    padding: 15px 100px;
}

.footerlinks {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.footerlinks a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.copywrite {
    font-size:120%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cafe Grinds</title>

<!---- Call External CSS---->
<link href="css/resetstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!----Call External File---->
<script src="js/modernizr-latest.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>

</head>

<body class="clearfix">
    <div id="wrapper">
  <header>

  </header>
<section>
    <div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>       
        <div class="delight">
        </div>
        <div class="comb">
        </div>
        <div class="reward">
        </div>
    </div>      
  </section>
<footer>
    <div class="links">
        <div class="footerlinks">
            <ul>
                <li> <h5>Customer Service</h5> </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Shipping</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">FAQ's</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footerlinks">
            <ul>
                <li> <h5>Online</h5> </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Gift Cards</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footerlinks">
            <ul>
                <li> <h5>Franchise</h5> </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Site Submittal</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Apply</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footerlinks">
            <ul>
                <li> <h5>Careers</h5> </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Opportunities</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Cafe</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Corporate</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="copywrite">
        &copy;Cafe Grind 2013
    </div>      
  </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the layout which it looks like from the above code

http://tinypic.com/r/2vao12x/5

how can i tile the bottom of the image so that i dont get the whole image repeat.

please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the image repeating you can just change the CSS

```
       background: url(bg.png) bottom no-repeat;
```

For a slideshow I would create a container for the slide show

```
     <div id="lightboxdiv"> 
      <a href="" id="lbImagelink">
           <img id="lbImage" src="" align="absmiddle">
       </a>
    </div>
```

then use some JS to change the image source on a timer event

```
        var lbImg= getelementbyid("lbImage");
        setTimeout(function(){lbImg.src =  imageurl ; },3000);
```

not sure this is what you want to do but hope it helps...